# Finding the value of the <title> in an HTML file using ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to create an automatically generate a table of contents page for a directory with a variable number of HTML files. I have created this:

```vb
<ul>
    <%
    dim fs,fo,x
    set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set fo=fs.GetFolder("c:\test\html\")

    for each x in fo.files
        newName=Split(x.Name, ".")
        'Print the name of all files in the test folder
        for each y in newName
            Response.write("<li><a href='" & x.Name & "'>" & y & "</a></li>")
        next
    next

    set fo=nothing
    set fs=nothing
    %>
</ul>
```

The problem here is that the links are generated using the file name, so I get things like "introduction" instead of "Introduction to This Topic." The `html > head > title` element in each HTML document is the link text I want to use. Is there a way I can extract it from each file?

(I am open to a solution that doesn't use ASP. I created this simply because it was what I had available to me. I'm not very familiar with ASP or its capabilities, so there might be a more efficient way to tackle this problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no saying that all of the files in a folder are actually used and are part of a site, or how these files relate in a sitemap structure. It's better to approach this from a crawler on the outside than a file-system on the inside.

There are various [sitemap generating services](http://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/) on the web that you can use. You can grab the results and edit them to suit your needs and post them as your own directory.

Comment: After trying a few different things, I ended up using a little Lua script with LuaXML to go through the files, extract some information, then generate a page. The Lua script is run automatically when the pages are changed. Not sure if this is the best way to go, but it works.